# How do I remove an upload item from a form?

Tags: javascript, file, upload

I have a form in which I allow files to be loaded using file input. I want to allow users to delete the upload item but I wasn't able to figure it out. Here is what I have tried to do so far:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST" align="right" id="post_form">
 <input type="file" id="upload_file" onChange="display()">
 <div id="show_button" onClick="remove_pic()">  remove </div><br>
</form>


function remove_pic() {
  alert('check');
  var file_loaded = document.getElementById("upload_file");
  file_loaded = null; // here i try to remove the object
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon running your code through JSFiddle and checking the Chrome dev console, I kept receiving a "Function not defined" error message.

I found that explicitly putting the function you're trying to call directly into the global scope allowed it to be recognized as defined. You'll also want to use a blank string instead of null and append a change to the ".value" property to your "file_loaded" variable.

Instead of

```
function remove_pic() {
  alert('check');
  var file_loaded = document.getElementById("upload_file");
  file_loaded = null; // here i try to remove the object
}
```

try

```
window.remove_pic = function() {
  alert('check');
  var file_loaded = document.getElementById("upload_file");
  file_loaded.value = ""; // here i try to remove the object 
};
```

Example JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xu6SD/1/

Comment: hi, acctually all i had to do is add the .value to the file_loaded. can you please explain why would you write this: "window.remove_pic = function()" i mean what is the meaning of this line?

Comment: It may have just been a quirk for JSFiddle, but it seemed like I had to explicitly put the function into the global scope for it to work. From what I understand, writing "window.remove_pic = function()" is just an explicit way to get the function into the global scope. I've also picked up writing "var functionName = function()" from [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742) - His argument is that it makes the definition of the function clearer and easier to read. Glad it worked, though! :)